# hadoop file system change directory command

Tags: hadoop

I was going through the HADOOP fs commands list. I am little perplexed not to find any "**cd**" command in hadoop fs.

Why is it so? It might sound silly question for the HADOOP users, but as I am beginner I can not understand why there is no list of cd command in HADOOP fs level?

Comment: You won't use the `cd` command when interacting with HDFS.Try to get hands-on experience; just reading the docs can be bit confusing since HDFS is not similar to other filesystems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think about it like this:

Hadoop has a special file system called "hdfs" which runs on top of existing say linux file system. There is no concept of current or present working directory a.k.a. pwd

Let's say we have following structure in hdfs:

```
d1/
  d2/
     f1
  d3/
     f2
     d4/
       f3
```

You could do cd in your Linux file system from moving from one to the other but do you think changing directory in hadoop would makes sense? HDFS is like virtual file system and you dont directly interact with hdfs except via hadoop command or job tracker.

Comment: @ almas shaikh: Thanks! so can we do "cd" from outside the HDFS i.e. from the linux file sytem? Please make me correct if I am having wrong concept.
Thanks!

Comment: No. You don't need it and cd is not supported by hadoop. You would just need to provide full path of file either while running mapred or be any hadoop command.

Comment: I think the solution re. mounting the filesystem thus allowing the shell to interact directly with it seems the appropriate solution here.

Answer (score 2):

HDFS provides various features that enable accessing HDFS(Hadoop Filesystem) easy on local machines or edge nodes. You have an option to mount HDFS using any of the following methods. Once Hadoop file system is mounted on your machine, you may use cd command to browse through the file system (It's is like mounting remote network filesystem like NAS)

- Fuse dfs (Available from Hadoop 0.20 onwards )
- NFSv3 Gateway access to HDFS data (Available from Hadoop version
  Hadoop 2.2.0)

Comment: thanks for the comment. I am using HADOOP 1.x version.

Comment: This sounds much more like what I'd expect the OP to need